# DynamoDB ValidationException The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to retrieve an item from DynamoDB with a Lambda function and always get the same error:

> ValidationException The provided key element does not match the schema

This is how I am currently attempting to pull the data. `myAttribute` is not a string, as seen [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/functions/dynamodb-from-js-lambda/q/platform/js/#getting-an-item-by-primary-key-in-dynamodb-from-lambda). Since `value` is a variable taken from `queryStringParamters`, I am using the [`DocumentClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) which supports native JS types:

```
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk")
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

  const getParams = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: { myAttribute: value },
  }

  ddb.get(getParams, function(error, data) {
    if (error)
    {
      console.log("get error", error)
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("get success", data)
    }
  })
```

Schema:

```
myTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: myTable
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: myAttribute
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: myOtherAttribute
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: myAttribute
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: myOtherAttribute
        KeyType: RANGE
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Some of my alternative approaches attempted can be found below. They're all based on various implementations I've seen in the docs. I've tried combinations of what is listed below, but I'm only listing a few to give an idea of what I've tried without making the post too long. For example, below I mention that I've tried specifying the API version while using `DocumentClient`. I've also attempted the same while not using the client.

Specifying `apiVersion`, as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html#dynamodb-example-document-client-get):

```
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2015-03-31" })
```

Attribute as a string, as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html#dynamodb-example-document-client-get):

```
  const getParams = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: { "myAttribute": value },
  }
```

Not using `DocumentClient`, and specifying `S` in the `Key` structure, as seen [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html#dynamodb-example-table-read-write-getting-an-item):

```
  const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2015-03-31" })

  const getParams = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: { "myAttribute": { S: value } },
  }
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here. I think I need to use `DocumentClient` since it supports native JS types, but no matter what kind of `Key` I use, the same error comes up. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely, the `get` method maps to the underlying `GetItem` API call, which requires you to specify the entire primary key. In your case, that means you need to provide both myAttribute and myOtherAttribute.

Comment: @Maurice I was wondering if that was the case, but what if I don't know the value of the second attribute? It would be a large JSON object with variable contents. Is there a way to use a wildcard `"*"` for the second attribute? I believe `get` does map to `getItem`

Comment: That's what you can use the `Query` API for, it will return all items that share the partition/hash key and allows you to optionally filter based on the sort key.

Comment: I came across that as well just now, and it works without error. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `get` method of the Document Client, which maps to the underlying `GetItem` API call. This API call requires the entire primary key to return the item. In your case, that means you would have to know the partition/hash and sort/range key of your item.

Since that's not the case as you mention in the comments, I suggest you use the `Query` API. Query operates on item collections (all items that share a partition key) and allows you to return the whole item collection or filter in the item collection based on the sort key.